# Fabricjs loadSVGFromURL issue

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I am trying to load svg from url, which I can control each elements from the svg objects. below is my code, and Im having hard time on how to deal with it.

```
var image = new fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function(objects,options) {
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length ; i++){        
    var obj = objects[i];   
    obj.setCoords();
    canvas.centerObject(obj);
    canvas.add(obj);
    canvas.item(i).hasControls = true;
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
```

});

How to add element by each object return from the objects callback and to be render individually to the canvas. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Done updating the above post.

Comment: I just realized that the code above run correctly but there were some positioning issues and I did not noticed that the controls of its elements is too small which i thought that it cannot be control.

Answer (score 0):

Just try following code, I hope it will fix your problem.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img){
    var img1 = img;
        img1.set({
        top : 0,
        left : 0,
        width : 100,
        height : 100
    });
    canvas.add(img1).setActiveObject(img1);
    canvas.centerObject(img1);
    obj.setCoords();
    canvas.item(i).hasControls = true;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```